# Proving $\frac12k+\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}(k-n)\cos(nx)=\frac{1-\cos(kx)}{4\sin^2(x/2)}$ for $k\geq2$ and $x\in \Bbb R\setminus 2\pi \Bbb Z$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

For $k\ge2$ we define

$$u_k(x)=\frac{k}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}(k-n)\cos(nx)$$

I want to prove that  for all $x\in \Bbb R\setminus 2\pi \Bbb Z$
$$u_k(x)=\frac{1-\cos(kx)}{4\sin^2(x/2)}$$

In fact I tried a direct proof but I lost in  the  calculation then I tried a proof by induction so the equality is easily verified for $k=2$ but I didn't find how prove the equality for $k+1$ assuming that's true for $k$.

Comment: Can you write down what you did by induction? And then precise the issue you have to complete the proof?

Comment: I found that $u_{k+1}(x)=u_k(x)+\sum_{n=1}^k\cos(nx)+\frac12$@mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^k\cos(nx)$ is well known or you can retrieved using the real part of the sum of the [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) $\sum_{n=1}^k e^{inx}$.

Comment: So how I find $\frac{1-\cos((k+1)x)}{4\sin^2(x/2)}$ from the last equality?

Comment: Can you please make the effort to update your question with the closed-form of $\sum_{n=1}^k\cos(nx)$? Everything is straight if you do so using some trigonometric formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
2u_k(x)\sin\frac{x}2&=k\sin\frac{x}2+\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}(k-n)\left[\sin\left(n+\frac12\right)x-\sin\left(n-\frac12\right)x\right]
\\&=\sum_{n=\color{red}{0}}^{k-1}(k-n)\sin\left(n+\frac12\right)x-\sum_{n=1}^{\color{red}{k}}(k-n)\sin\left(n-\frac12\right)x
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^k(k-n+1)\sin\left(n-\frac12\right)x-\sum_{n=1}^k(k-n)\sin\left(n-\frac12\right)x
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^k\sin\left(n-\frac12\right)x\qquad\text{implies}
\\4u_k(x)\sin^2\frac{x}2&=\sum_{n=1}^k\big(\cos(n-1)x-\cos nx\big)=1-\cos kx.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you! This is the direct proof I looked for:-)